# How to append every nth in a sequence?

Tags: python

If I have a list:

```
["a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "b2", "c2", "a3", "b3", "c3"]
```

and I want to make a new list like:

```
["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

I am trying to do this in a for loop so that I'm appending to a new list in sequence:

```
newlist = []
for i in oldlist:
    newlist.append(oldlist[i])
    newlist.append(oldlist[2*i])
    newlist.append(oldlist[3*i])
    i+3
```

The problem with my code is that it will append all values of `i` or `i*3` first in one go, rather than letting each `n`th version of i have a chance.

Comment: You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function to sort your list if that's your end goal.

Answer (score 5):

You could stride though the sequence with desired offsets, the use `itertools` to flatten back into a 1D list.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> d =  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([d[::3], d[1::3], d[2::3]]))
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

You could also do something similar using `numpy` by reshaping the array, transposing, then flattening again

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d =  np.array(['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'])
>>> np.reshape(d, (d.size//3, 3)).T.flatten()
array(['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'], dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you want the interval to be n=3

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,11,22,33,111,222,333]
>>> res=[]
>>> n=3
>>> for i in range(0,n):
...     for z in a[i::n]:
...         res.append(z)
... 
>>> 
>>> res
[1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222, 3, 33, 333]
```

More pythonic

```
>>> a=['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3']
>>> res = [val for i in range(3) for val in a[i::3]]
>>> res
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

where `a[i::3]` just traverses the list starting from ith index in steps of 3.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting feature of `zip` is it's ability to group an input into groups of fixed length without explicit slicing. [The `grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) lets you convert to groups of fixed length, which you can then unpack for another round of `zip`ing such that you pair up the first elements of each group:

```
>>> lst = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "b2", "c2", "a3", "b3", "c3", 'a4', 'b4', 'c4']  # Added three more elements so it's clear it's three groups of four, three of three being harder to see
>>> list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))  # Grouped sequentially so a is first element of each group
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
 ('a4', 'b4', 'c4')]

>>> list(zip(*zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))) # Unpack and zip again to group a's with a's, b's with b's, etc.
[('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'), ('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'), ('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4')]

>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))))  # Flatten out to single list
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

You can achieve the same result with:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(lst[i::3] for i in range(3)))
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

multi-`zip` just pushes all the work to built-ins (no Python level looping at all). Plus the latter is two whole characters longer, and seems too similar to CoryKramer's answer. :-) That said, the latter is superior if your input is not of even length; `zip` stops iterating when the shortest iterable is exhausted, while `itertools.zip_longest` has to use filler values. Actual slicing and flattening avoids that issue.

Comment: I never understand why something so simple deserves these atrocious looking codes that’s just a headache to look at, let alone understand.

Comment: @darksky: :-D I'm not really recommending this approach. The code near the end (`chain`ing a generator expression producing slices) is fine, but the rest is mostly just for fun. If I were to use the earlier code, I'd use it solely after defining the `grouper` recipe, so it would look like `list(zip(*grouper(lst, 3))`, which still isn't great, but is clearly less ugly.